# Prove that $n^3=n \text{ mod }6$ for every integer $n$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, integers

Prove that for every integer $n$ , $n^3=n \text{ mod }6$

I was having no clue how to do this, then I thought of case-by-case analysis and obviously it worked. The problem is that there were six case and together they are long.

**Is there any shorter method of proving this. Kindly provide some hints.**

Comment: Fermat's little theorem? Or $n^3-n=n(n+1)(n-1)$. Or simply, Euler's theorem if you know that.

Comment: Hmm, wait, probably Euler's theorem won't work. But the factorization is the best :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Factorize $n^3-n$. Is any of these factors even? Is any of these factors a multiple of three?

Answer (score 3):

$n^3-n=n(n+1)(n-1)$ is always divisible by 2 and 3, so it is 0 mod 6.

**Note:** I marked this answer community wiki because I got the answer form the comment.

Answer (score 1):

The direct approach:

$$0^3 \equiv 0 \mod 6$$
$$1^3 \equiv 1 \mod 6$$
$$2^3 \equiv 8 \equiv 2 \mod 6$$
$$3^3 \equiv 27 \equiv 3 \mod 6$$
$$4^3 \equiv (-2)^3 \equiv -8 \equiv -2 \equiv 4 \mod 6$$
$$5^3 \equiv (-1)^3 \equiv -1 \equiv 5 \mod 6$$

Thus $$n^3 \equiv n \mod 6$$ by exhaustive checking.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use purely modular arithmetic, then you must prove that both 3 and 2 divide your function. So, we use Fermat's little theorem.

Clearly, $n^3 \equiv n (\bmod 3) \implies n^3 - n \equiv 0 (\bmod 3)$

So, 3 divides this.

Now we move on to 2, with Fermat's little theorem again,

$n^2 \equiv n (\bmod 2) \implies n^3 \equiv n^2 \equiv n (\bmod 2)$, or, through transitivity, $n^3 - n \equiv 0 (\bmod 2)$. Thus, 2 and 3 divide this function, which immediately implies that 6 must also divide it, ie $n^3 - n \equiv 0 (\bmod 6)$.

Answer (score 0):

Carmichael's function $\lambda(6)=\text{lcm}(\phi(3), \phi(2)) = 2$, and $6$ is square-free, so $n^{k\lambda(6)+c} \equiv n^c \bmod 6 \: (c>0)$ . And in particular, $n^3\equiv n\mod 6$.

In the same way, $n^{13} \equiv n \bmod 910$.